# Trouble finding the length in the string

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, bios

I found the code here, on Stack Overflow to get the length of the string. Here's the code:

```
HELLO_MSG: db 'Hello, world!', 0
mov ebx, HELLO_MSG
call print_string

print_string:
 call str_len
 mov ecx, eax ; puts the length of the called string into ecx register
 cdq          ; clear the direction flag; not sure if this is needed
 mov ah, 0x0e ; scrolling teleype BIOS routine

 printing:
    mov al, byte bl
    int 0x10
    inc ebx
    loop printing

 ret
str_len:
 mov eax,ebx

 l00p:
    cmp byte[eax], 0
    jz lpend
    inc eax
    jmp l00p
 lpend:
    sub eax, ebx ; puts the length of the string into eax register

    ret
```

The problem is that when function calls `str_len`, it loops only 3 times, sometimes it does 2 times. And when it prints, it doesn't print the actual string, but some random letters. Does anybody know why it doesn't work? I'm trying to run it in the boot sector, so I don't really have any debugging tools.

Comment: Do you have your program offsets set properly?

Comment: I have declared the code to start at `[org 0x7c00]`, that's the only other thing I've set up. I haven't setup base and stack pointers yet, because I'm not really using them within these printing strings. Could that affect it?

Comment: Is that the full source code? What's to say that execution will start at the first `mov` instruction and not in the `HELLO_MSG` string (i.e. executing garbage)? Also, the instruction used for clearing the direction flag is `cld`, not `cdq` (`cdq` is used for sign-extending `eax` into `edx` prior to a division).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more problems in your code:

1. You should jump over string constant on the beginning

   ```
   mov ebx, HELLO_MSG
   call print_string
   jmp $

   HELLO_MSG: db 'Hello, world!', 0

   print_string:
   ...
   ```
2. `cdq` instruction is not for clearing `DF`. `cdq` is used to convert doubleword in `eax` into sign-extended `edx:eax` value. You should `cld` instead. But you're right, when you don't use any string instructions (`cmpsb`, `movsb`...), `DF` usually isn't important.
3. > I haven't setup base and stack pointers yet, because I'm not really using them within these printing strings.

   Yes, but you use `call` instruction, which pushes return address on stack. Usually, BIOS "allocates" small space for stack before running bootloader, so it shouldn't affect anything.
4. This line

   ```
    mov al, byte bl
   ```

   will set `AL` equal to `BL`, which is not the thing you want. You should use indirect byte addressing with `ebx`.

   ```
   mov al, byte [ebx]
   int 0x10
   inc ebx
   ...
   ```

Comment: 1. Yeah I do that in the actual code, but here was just a snippet of printing.
2. I don't know how I came up with cdq... Sorry about that.
3. I totally didn't think of that. Thanks for letting me know.
4. This fixed it! I appreciate your help! Thank you.